# How to initialize builder class members with dummy values while calling cls.builder.param().build()

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, lombok, builder

I need to initialize my builder class members with some Dummy values while calling .param()

```
@Builder
public class MyQuery {
       private String param1;
       private String param1;
       private String param1;
       private String param1;
       ...
       private String param100;
}
```

When I call the builder class like below, I want them to be initialized with some dummy value(or empty string) and the rest should be null. If I use the LOMBOK builder, it has to be initialized with some value as .param1("some string"). Is there any library which can help me here.

```
    MyQuery query = MyQuery.builder()
            .param1()
            .param2()
            .param3()
            .build();
```

whichever parameter I call, should have some dummy value(non-null, could be empty as well).

Comment: You can simply assign default values and add `@Builder.Default` on those fields.

Comment: If I use @Builder.Default, the same parameters will have the default values all the time. I want something like: if I call .PARAM1(), then only PARAM1 value should be assigned to default. And any of the parameters I can use while calling builder()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the lombok builder doc, I realized that I could do something as follows. Lombok will not generate the resources if a resource with the same name already exists. This approach will still reduce some of the boiler plate codes.

```
import lombok.Builder;

    @Builder
    public class MyQuery {

        private static final String SOME_STRING = "This is needed"; 
        private String paramWithNoSpecialCase // This is any other parameter, lombok will generate the builder for this.
        private String param1;
        private String param2;
        private String param3;


        public static class MyQueryBuilder {

            public MyQuery.MyQueryBuilder param1() {
                this.param1 = SOME_STRING;
                return this;
            }
            public MyQuery.MyQueryBuilder param2() {
                this.param1 = SOME_STRING;
                return this;
            }
            public MyQuery.MyQueryBuilder param3() {
                this.param1 = SOME_STRING;
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
```